# Proving continuity and differentiability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

let $f(x)=\sin |x|, x\in (-\pi,\pi)$. Is $f$ continuous on $(-\pi,\pi)$ ? Is it differentiable in that interval ?

I have read continuity at a point. How do i prove it for an interval ?

Comment: It is continuous on a set if it is continuous for all points on the set. That is the definition of continuity of a function on a set.

Comment: @GitGud yeah, so say if i consider a point in the given interval say $c$ how do i extend it ? can i just say that $sin x$ is obviously continuous everywhere in the given interval ?

Comment: You haven't told us what you are allowed to assume. You have not even told us what definition you are using for the sine function.

Comment: What do you mean with 'extend it'? Even though $\sin$ is continuous, that's not enough to guarantee that $x\mapsto \sin (|x|)$ is.

Comment: @GitGud by extend i meant that if i show that at $c$ it is continuous how do i show that this is true for every point ? I understand that second point. I tried breaking the function for the intervals $(-\pi,0) \ and (0,\pi)$ but was stuck at how to actually show that it holds good at every point. Is it workable this way ?

Comment: @AmanMittal If I'm not mistaken you're lacking some basic logical concepts. I can't help you now, though. I'm out for a bit. Try asking dfeuer to expand his hint.

Comment: I fear we may be jumping too far into the deep end here, before you've attained a full understanding of more basic concepts. If you're using a textbook, I strongly suggest that you flip back to the chapter on limits and continuity, read it over a bit more, and then sit down and do *all the exercises*, or at least several from each subsection. This is a painful and time-consuming process, but continuity is a really important and fundamental concept that is well worth getting down really solidly.

Comment: @dfeuer : yeah right, i better get back to basics. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint on continuity: $f$ is the composition of two functions, absolute value and sine. What do you know about continuity and composition?

Hint on differentiability: What point in $(-\pi,\pi)$ is a little weird for the absolute value function? How does that affect the sine function there?

**Added hint:**

Calculate $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}.$$

Comment: ok i get the continuity point. for differentiability, the absolute function fails at $0$, can your explain a little more on how that affects diff of the given function ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: I added another hint.

Comment: hmm okie, i get a $-1$ and a $+1$ , as they are different, the function must not be differentiable. is that rirght ?

Comment: Well, you should get $1$ and $-1$, and that is why it's not differentiable, but you have to explain how you get those, which takes a little more trickery!

Comment: yeah, by putting for negative and positive values for $|x|$ right ?

Comment: @Aman Mittal, I'm not sure what you mean. Why don't you click on "Answer your own question" and try to come up with a convincing argument we can critique?

Comment: yeah, let me write it

Comment: I have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

for checking differentiability of $f(x)=\sin |x|$ in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ :

The only doubtful point for differentiability of the function in the given point is $(0,0)$. If the function is diff there, $Rf'(0)=Lf'(0)$

$$Rf'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {f(0+h)-f(0)\over h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{sin h-0\over h}=1$$

$$LRf'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {f(0-h)-f(0)\over -h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{-sin(-h)-0\over -h}=-1$$

As $Rf'(0)\ne Lf'(0)$ The given function is not differentiable every point in the interval. Hence it is not differentiable in the interval.

Comment: Not quite? Swapping the signs for $h$ in the intermediate form doesn't help you any, and you need to be more explicit about the left/right distinction.